# How to fire an event when the tab key is pressed in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

For the current application I am working on I want to simulate a combo box using my own custom control as I want it to be multi column and have some additional functionality. I am using a text box and a datagridview to do this.

I want to replicate the suggest/append that can be used with a regular combo box. I've got this working great. The user can begin to type, gets a list of suggestions and can use the up and down keys to scroll through entries.

I have already trapped the enter key to take the selected row as the value. This works perfectly but I would also like to trap the tab key and do the same, much like the functionality already embedded in a combo box control.

The problem is that, obviously vb.net uses the tab key to change the selected control and this fires before I can call my subroutine to take the selected row from my datagridview. I want to be able to cancel tabbing out of the control, or at least find a way to fire my code before it does.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TextBox also has an `AcceptsTab` property that works when `Multiline = True`.

With those conditions, you can now see if the tab key was pressed:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
                             Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    'do something
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

the problem is in this case that pressing TAB key will loose focus on that input element
you need to bind on keydown event
and with callback function like this

```
   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (code == '9') {
     alert('Tab');
     return false;
   }
```

Comment: i guess logic behind is the same