# Capture keys.TAB on KeyDown

Tags: vb.net, tabs, keydown, onkeydown

I am trying to capture TAB keypress on Keydown Event.
I can see another post on [How to fire an event when the tab key is pressed in a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969141/how-to-fire-an-event-when-the-tab-key-is-pressed-in-a-textbox)

However, On the above link, posted solution is not working for me which I mentioned below.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) _
                         Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
       e.SuppressKeyPress = True
       'do something
    End If
End Sub
```

For the testing purpose, I have added 2 simple textboxes on FORM1 and write the below code to capture the TAB on KeyDown event.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        MsgBox("TAB DOWN")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Me.Text = e.KeyChar
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        MsgBox("TAB UP")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
    Me.Text = "LEAVE"
End Sub
```

My above code should suppose to display a message box on KeyDown when TAB is press. It's not working.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a new event called PreviewKeyDown()

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        Me.Text = "TAB Capture From TextBox1_KeyDown At " & Now.ToString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        Me.Text = "TAB Capture From TextBox1_PreviewKeyDown At " & Now.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

If you will execute the above code, you will able to capture TAB key on PreviewKeyDown() event.

Answer (score -2):

`MsgBox()` is a holdover from VB6 and you should use the .NET implementation of a message box, like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("TAB UP")
```

Also, you are setting a `Text` property against the instance of the form class (`Me`), when I think you intend to set the `Text` property of the text box, like this:

```
Me.TextBox1.Text = e.KeyChar
```

Comment: MessageBox.show or MsgBox is not my concern here because MsgBox is also working for me.

Comment: I am using Me.Text to set the FORM heading so this is work working fine for me.

Comment: might be my question is not very clear to you. basically I am trying to capture TAB Key on KeyDown event.